# How can i implement opening a file with my java program?

Tags: java, file, file-io, drag-and-drop

I have a basic, simple and maybe stupid question, but how do I implement that I can drag a file onto my java program and open it?
I searched really long for this basic question.....

As long as I found out you can't implement dragging it onto the .jar, because its not executable. You have to create a .exe, which also open your .jar, but that's all! I would really like to know how :)

A keyword would be enough, if I can get the answer through searching this keyword.

Thanks, Leander

//Edit: I may have expressed things a little bit complicated.
Later i want to have a shortcut on, for example, the desktop where i can drag any file on the shortcut and the programm opens with the file(it will, at this point) only move it to a special location.

*I don´t know how the code for this would be, I even don't know how to google for this (I only get questions how to implement "open with" with the answer Desktop.open(File f)).*

Comment: Depends on the operating system, I suspect.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/125343/windows-open-with-with-java-and-a-jar-file

Comment: What do you mean with "only move it to a special location"? You cannot have the jar to have drag'n'drop but you can have a shortcut that adds the "drag'n'drop" capability and then you must handle it in you code (See my answer)

Comment: If it is a path the programm wil just copy the file to a special location depending on your time and day and then delete the orginal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The place to start reading is the [JDK 6 documentation on Drag and Drop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/dragndrop/index.html). Or else you can start directly with the [Drag and Drop tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html).

If you want to create a desktop icon that will open your app when you drop a file on it, this depends on the OS. I think that [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) will support this, although I haven't used it in this way.

Comment: His problem is how to launch the program when he drags over some icon , not how to make D&D work once the program is running, I think.

Comment: @bmargulies - Ah. If that's the case, then as you point out in your comment, it all depends on the OS. You might be able to do something with Launch4j.

Comment: hmm, i searched the whole webpage and i still don´t know how i can implement it. Will a argument in the main method contain a path to the object?

Comment: @user1080014 - When you drop files on an app icon, I think Windows by default will construct a command line with the file names. So--yes, they will be args to `main(String[]args)`. (Whether they will be the only args depends on what command line you specify that Launch4j should use when creating the desktop shortcut.) I don't know if it's possible to use the IDropTarget mechanism that Windows provides to give you more control.

Answer (score 4):

For windows only:

**option 1:**

make a batch file into the directory of your jar file (or anywhere you like but then you need to adjust the path, you can also make a shortcut from the batch file).

```
@ECHO OFF
start java -jar %~dp0MYAPP.jar %1
```

**option 2:**

- Make a shortcut (right click - new - shortcut)
- Enter into the location "java -jar C:\path\to\myapp.jar"

drag and drop will work if your jar accepts filename as a parameter

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length == 0)
            System.out.println("No arguments");
        else
            System.out.println("1st argument: " + args[0]);
    }

}
```

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. My JAR had a shortcut to it on the windows desktop, but that contained only the path to the JAR file, not the java command. I changed that and it worked. I just used javaw instead of java command to avoid the DOS window. In my eyes, option two solves the question. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

On window you can create .bat file, and if you DnD on that file you get filename as fisrt parameter

so code

```
echo %1
pause
```

writes the filename out, so you can start you java program like

```
java -jar myApp.jar MyAppClass %1
```